# power spectral density-scipy.signal

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

While trying to compute the Power spectral density with an acquisition rate of 300000hz using ... signal.periodogram(x, fs,nfft=4096) , I get the graph upto 150000Hz and not upto 300000. Why is this upto half the value ? What is the meaning of sampling rate here?

In the example given in scipy documentation , the sampling rate is 10000Hz but we see in the plot only upto 5000Hz.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html

Comment: You cannot sample a 300 kHz signal with a sampling rate (acquisition rate) of 300 kHz, this would be one sample per cycle of signal, and you need a minimum of two. See [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). This explains why tools will not process up to the sampling rate, but only up to half of the sampling rate.

Answer (score 2):

The spectrum of real-valued signal is always symmetric with respect to the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) (half of the sampling rate). As a result, there is often no need to store or plot the redundant symmetric portion of the spectrum.

If you still want to see the whole spectrum, you can set the `return_onesided` argument to `True` as follows:

```
f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs, return_onesided=False)
```

The resulting plot of the same example provided in [`scipy.periodogram` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html) would then cover a 10000Hz frequency range as would be expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you check the length of `f` in the example:

```
>>> len(f)
>>> 50001
```

This is NOT 50000 Hz. This is because `scipy.signal.periodogram` calls `scipy.signal.welch` with the parameter `nperseg=x.shape[-1]` by default. This is the correct input for `scipy.signal.welch`. However, if dig into [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/signal/spectral.py#L143) and see lines 328-329 (as of now), you'll see the reason why the size of output is 50001.

```
if nfft % 2 == 0:  # even
   outshape[-1] = nfft // 2 + 1
```